# Install Apache, PHP and MySQL on different servers

Tags: php, apache, ssh, cloud, openstack

I have deployed a cloud using `OpenStack` and have `VM`s running in the cloud and I am also able to `PING`/`SSH` between those `VM`s.

I want to install `Apache`, `PHP`, and `MySQL` on three different nodes(As I mentioned that I can `SSH` between those nodes/`VM`s).

Is there any guide how to do this? or where do I have to change the `conf` files to make this working together?

Comment: I guess, Apache and PHP can/should run on the same node. And the MySQL should be instaled on other node. 

Any better idea?

Answer (score 3):

If you have your VM instances ready, you can install the required services on those instances using the package manager very easily using yum or apt-get depending on what distro you are using.
You will need to run some simple commands on those VMs.
Apache and php will work on the same VM and install the mysql separately on another VM.